# str_replace not working as expcted php

Tags: php

str_replace is not finding the string and replacing like it should.

This is the $data string that is outputted by echo

```
 eth0 192.168.1.1/24 u/u Local eth0.51 192.168.5.1/24 u/u Dev 1 eth1  x.x.x.x/24 u/u Internet eth2 192.168.2.1/24 u/D Local 2 lo 127.0.0.1/8 u/u ::1/128 tun35 192.168.4.222/24 u/u
```

Here is my code

```
  $ssh = new Net_SSH2("$routerip");
  if (!$ssh->login("$username", "$password")) {
  return $radioip["error"] ='router error';
  }

 $data = $ssh->exec("/opt/vyatta/bin/vyatta-op-cmd-wrapper show interfaces");

$string = 'eth';  

$datastart = strpos($data,$string);
$datastart = $datastart -1;

$pattern ='lo 127.0.0.1/8 u/u ::1/128';
$replace = '';  
echo "$pattern";
$data = substr($data,$datastart);
$data = str_replace($pattern,$replace, $data);
echo "$data";
```

Edit

This is $data before substr

```
 Codes: S - State, L - Link, u - Up, D - Down, A - Admin Down Interface IP  Address S/L Description --------- ---------- --- ----------- eth0 192.168.1.1/24   u/u Local eth0.51 192.168.5.1/24 u/u Dev 1 eth1 x.x.x.x/24 u/u Internet eth2 192.168.2.1/24 u/D Local 2 lo 127.0.0.1/8 u/u ::1/128 tun35 192.168.4.222/24 u/u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in line

```
$datastart = $datastart -1;
```

If `$datastart` is 0 (which is true in your case as `eth` is in the beginning of the string), then `$datastart -1;` makes `$datastart` equals `-1`.

Which in case affects `$data = substr($data,$datastart);` because negative offset changes the `$data` string to just `u`. In which you definintely don't have your `$pattern`.

I think the simpliest way will be to check if `$datastart` is less then 0 and set it to zero:

```
$datastart = strpos($data,$string);
if ($datastart < 0) {
    $datastart = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please relook as $data is different for those lines

Comment: It dose work. I was using a search string that was missing all the extra spaces